# Making the player face an actor in Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

How can I make the player face an actor or object using blueprints? Imagine a game like 4D Sports Boxing. The camera is in a fixed position and the player should always face the enemy.
I've already made the camera, but I can't figure out how to make the player face the enemy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for finding the look direction and its very easy in the newer versions. [Find look at rotation function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x5Ht.png)

simply take the object you want to look at. In this case, your enemy actor and/or pawn. Get the enemy's location and get your cameras rotation (world rotation for both) and connect it to the function
Camera = Start
Enemy = Target
Then plug the rotation end into the camera world rotation, this should make a pretty primitive look at thing for your character to use (you can refine it later)